# Steam.app would like to receive keystrokes from any application

Tags: security, catalina, privacy, games, steam

I just installed a new version of Steam on macOS Catalina 10.15 (19A602) and got this unexpected request:

> Keystroke Receiving
>
> Steam.app would like to receive keystrokes from any application

[image: Keystroke Receiving: Steam.app would like to receive keystrokes from any application]

I hit `Deny` since I can't see any good reason why Steam should need this. I can't find any answers, having looked at a thread on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ThemeParkitect/comments/dgna1g/parkitect_would_like_to_receive_keystrokes_from/) and [Apple Support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250720391). This security article from Sophos, [Synthetic clicks and the macOS flaw Apple can’t seem to fix](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2019/06/04/synthetic-clicks-and-the-macos-flaw-apple-cant-seem-to-fix/) seems to be related.

Why would Steam need this?

Comment: The steam overlay.  It needs to receive keystrokes while you're playing other games.

Comment: Appreciate apple security here.. and its total violation of privacy. What if later on application developer try to mis use users data such as passwords.
I was also astonished to see this kind of pop-up and I denied too. App is working fine, Steam needs to find some other way to work with their overlay.

Answer (score 1):

> Under Catalina's security model, Apps are supposed to operate isolated
>   from everything else, including your data. If they want to use your
>   data or a service from another App, they must ask you for permission
>   to do so.

[Source.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250720391?answerId=251408897022#251408897022)

This seems reasonable given the message in the dialog box, however I can find no direct information directly from Apple so please take it under advisement until it can be confirmed.